# What is the difference between assigning null to an instance of a class and just declaration

Tags: c#, null, declaration

I'm trying to understand if there is any difference between assigning null to an instance of a class and just declaring the class.

For an example, I have a class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string FirstProperty { get; set; }
    public int SecondProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I declare two instances of the class:

```
MyClass Instance1 = null;
MyClass Instance2;  // just declaration
```

Is there any difference between `Instance1` and `Instance2`?

If yes, is it safe? Is it a good habit to use the 'delcaration only' style (as is the case with `Instance2` in the example above)?

Comment: The former is a variable which was initialized with `null`, the latter is a varibale which isn't initialized explicitly, so gets the default value which is null too. Difference is: readability, everyone knows that the null is desired and expected. If you have an `out` paramater the compiler forces you to assign something, even if it's `null`.

Comment: For example Resharper will suggest to remove an `null` assignment in this case.

Comment: Yes there's a difference. In the second case, if the value is a field it will be automatically assigned the default value, but if it's a local variable it won't. If it is then "read" by the code, this leads to the compiler error "use of unassigned local variable"

Comment: Many times I saw just a declaration of an instance in someones code. Trying to understand if it right to do or not. Thanks, for comments guys.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your answers. All of your answers helps a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Then I'm creating two instances of the class:

You're not creating any instances. You're creating two places to put instances if they are ever created. The first you've explicitly said does not have an instance, they second just doesn't have one.

> Is there any difference between `Instance1` and `Instance2`?

It depends on where you've done that.

If that code is within a `class` or `struct` then you've created two fields, both of which will be set to `null` initially, unless a constructor does something else.

If you've that code within a method (including a constructor or property accessor) then you've got two local variables (though the convention would be to use lower-case here).

The first has been set to null and you can do things with it that are valid to do with null (pass it to a method [though it *may* throw an exception if it refuses to accept null) compare it with something to confirm that it is indeed null or isn't indeed the same as something that really does have an instance.

The second has not been assigned and therefore it is illegal to do anything other than assign it something (whether null, or an instance). Any attempt to do anything before it's definitely been set will be a compiler error. E.g.:

```
MyClass Instance2;
if (valueThatJustHappensToAlwaysBeTrue)
{
   Instance2 = new MyClass();
}
bool isNull = Instance2 == null; // Error! Not guaranteed to be assigned strongly enough for the compiler to know.
```

> Is yes, is it safe and it's a good habit to have `Instance2` with declaration only?

When possible, it's a good habit to be declaring as close to the first assignment (the initialisation) as possible, ideally at the same time:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
```

However, if you've a few different possible paths, such as:

```
MyClass instance;
if (boolValue)
{
   instance = new MyClass(1); // Yes, I know there's no int-taking ctor on your class, but it defeats the argument when the bare constructor is the only one available, so let's say there is.
}
else if (otherBoolValue)
{
   throw new SomeException();
}
else if (someIntValue > 42)
{
   instance = new MyClass(3);
}
else
{
   instance = new MyClass(9);
}
```

Now, it's impossible to get to the end of this chain with an uninitialised `instance`. Either it will have been set, or the exception will have been thrown. If we'd thought it might be "safer" to start with `MyClass instance = null` then we'd have perhaps hidden a mistake. The logic above is meant to assign it something for every path and because of the rule that you can't use an instance that isn't guaranteed to be assigned then a mistake in that would cause a compiler error, and the mistake would be obvious. If it's assigned to a "placeholder" null to begin with such a mistake isn't going to be quite as immediately obvious, and could cause a bug.

So in cases like bare declaration is better.

But that said, complicated logic is always better avoided when possible, so those sort of convoluted chains should be rare. In other cases the style of declaring and assigning at the same point means you've no gap between the two where a mistake can slip in.

Comment: Thaks for your answer, now I understand when and why to use MyClasss instance;

Answer (score 5):

In your examples, you are not creating any *instance*. You declare two *variables*.

To the first one you explicitly *assign* `null`. To the second you don't assign anything. Therefor it contains the default value, which is `null` for reference types.<sup>1</sup>

Technically, there now is no difference between the *values* of those two *variables*. But the compiler may raise an error if you try to use the value of `Instance2` because the compiler does not allow to use uninitialized variables:

```
MyClass Instance1 = null;
MyClass Instance2;
Console.WriteLine(Instance1); // fine
Console.WriteLine(Instance2); // raises error CS0165
```

---

<sup>1</sup>As stuartd and Kyle commented, local variables may not be initialised at all by the compiler, which explains the error. You cannot rely on the variable having any specific value before you assign one, whether `null` or an created instance of `MyClass`. Fields and properties are initialised to the default value of the type (`null` for reference types).

Comment: In the case of local variables does it matter that the uninitialized variable will actually contain null?  The compiler won't let you access an uninitialized local, so does it really matter what it contains?

Comment: @Kyle right, after seeing stuartd's comment I'm not so sure if local variables are initialized at all... probably not, why else would the compiler throw that error...just trying to get the wording right to edit my answer.

Comment: @RenéVogt take a look on Jon Hanna's answer. He has a good explanation.  By the way, thanks, for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `null` keyword is a literal that represents a `null` reference, one that does not refer to any object. `null` is the default value of **reference-type** variables. Ordinary value types cannot be `null`.

**Example:**

```
 class Program
    {
        class MyClass
        {
            public void MyMethod() { }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Set a breakpoint here to see that mc = null.
            // However, the compiler considers it "unassigned."
            // and generates a compiler error if you try to
            // use the variable.
            // try Console.WriteLine(mc);
            // it will return error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable `mc'
            MyClass mc;

            // Now the variable can be used, but...
            mc = null;

            // ... a method call on a null object raises 
            // a run-time NullReferenceException.
            // Uncomment the following line to see for yourself.
            // mc.MyMethod();

            // Now mc has a value.
            mc = new MyClass();

            // You can call its method.
            mc.MyMethod();

            // Set mc to null again. The object it referenced
            // is no longer accessible and can now be garbage-collected.
            mc = null;
       }
```

Answer (score -2):

They are the same.

In fact, if you are using ReSharper, it will tell you that the "= null" is redundant.

as for your second question.  I don't declare a lot of variables without immediately assigning to them.

so if your just declaring it like

```
MyClass Instance2;
```

then setting it.

```
MyClass = new Instance2;

Instance2.FirstProperty = "some string";
Instance2.SecondProperty = 1;
```

That can all get combined in a single statement

```
var MyClass = new Instance2 { FirstProperty = "some string", SecondProperty = 1 };
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @InBetween how do you figure?  first question.  they are the same.  second question is it good to just declare variables.  no, in most instances you want to initialize them.

Comment: The OP is asking what is the difference between `MyClass instance1` and `MyClass instance2 = null`. The former is an uninitialized variable and the later is a variable initialized to `null`, which are two very different things as far as the compiler is concerned.